# Error connect Shopify data to SQL Server by SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, type-conversion, shopify, etl

I am using SSIS+ 2.0.101.2677 with Visual Studio 15.9.28307.1800, targeting SQL Server 2017.

I follow your video [Connect Shopify to MS SQL Server. Easy Shopify & SQL Server integration. Load, Export and Sync data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSMjoRTYEls&ab_channel=COZYROC)

Connect Shopify to SQL Server. Easy Shopify & SQL Server integration. Load, Export, and Sync data

In last step start connect shopify REST Source to OLE DB Destination (I create table in my database), I got this error:

> TITLE: Package Validation Error
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [316]]: Column "title" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [316]]: Column "vendor" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "OLE DB Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation. (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

Does someone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The main error you are facing is:

> cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode string data types

This error is thrown since you are trying to insert a Unicode string value (nvarchar) into a non-Unicode string column (varchar).

You can simply add a derived column or a data conversion transformation to solve this issue. Or you can change the target columns data type to `nvarchar`.

You can refer to the following links for alternatives and more guidance:

- [Solving an SSIS Error – Cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-an-ssis-error-%E2%80%93-cannot-convert-between-unicode-and-non-unicode)
- [SSIS Data Conversion Between Unicode and Non-Unicode Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367560/ssis-data-conversion-between-unicode-and-non-unicode-error)